# Multiple If-Then-Else not validating for JSON Schema

Tags: json, jsonschema

I have a program that I have built that takes a JSON object and produces a JSON schema file based on the details of the input. When I use this program to generate a schema for a smaller JSON object, the schema works correctly and validates as expected. In this smaller schema there is only one if-then-else block.

However when I attempt to generate a schema that makes use of several if-then-else blocks the if-then-else validation seems to stop working at all and will allow anything through.

I'll post an example below to be more clear.

JSON Schema

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
  "definitions": {
    "question6-99": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "answer": {
          "type": "string",
          "enum": ["Yes", "No"]
        }
      }
    },
    "question6-100": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "answer": {
          "type": "string",
          "enum": ["Mr","Ms","Mrs","Miss","Dr","Rev","Sir","Lady","Lord","Prof", ""]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "form_submission": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "sections": {
          "type": "object",
          "properties": {
            "6": {
              "type": "object",
              "properties": {
                "questions": {
                  "type": "object",
                  "properties": {
                    "99": {
                      "$ref": "#/definitions/question6-99"
                    },
                    "100": {
                      "$ref": "#/definitions/question6-100"
                    }
                  },
                  "if": {
                    "properties": {
                      "99": {
                        "properties": {
                          "answer": {
                            "enum": [
                              "Yes"
                            ]
                          }
                        },
                        "required": [
                          "answer"
                        ]
                      }
                    },
                    "required": [
                      "100"
                    ]
                  },
                  "then": {
                    "properties": {
                      "100": {
                        "properties": {
                          "answer": {
                            "minLength": 1
                          }
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  },
                  "else": {
                    "properties": {
                      "100": {
                        "properties": {
                          "answer": {
                            "maxLength": 0
                          }
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          },
          "required": [
            "6"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

JSON Object being validated

```
{
  "form_submission": {
    "sections": {
      "1": {
        "questions": {
          "99": {
            "answer": "Yes",
          },
          "100": {
            "answer": "",
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

For the above example, if the schema is used to validate the object, the answer for question 100 must be answered when question 99 is answered "yes". This works correctly.

However if I then attempt to use the schema below, which uses two if-then-else blocks against the second JSON object, no if-then-else validation occurs.

I'm just wondering if I have done something wrong with the structure of my schema code that is stopping the validation from happening correctly.

Schema using two If-then-else

```
{
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
    "definitions": {
        "question6-99": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "answer": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "minLength": 1,
                    "enum": ["Yes", "No"]
                }
            }
        },
        "question6-100": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "answer": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "enum": ["Mr", "Ms", "Mrs", "Miss", "Dr", "Rev", "Sir", "Lady", "Lord", "Prof", ""]
                }
            }
        },
        "question6-101": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "answer": {
                    "type": "string"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "form_submission": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "sections": {
                    "type": "object",
                    "properties": {
                        "6": {
                            "type": "object",
                            "properties": {
                                "questions": {
                                    "type": "object",
                                    "properties": {
                                        "99": {
                                            "$ref": "#/definitions/question6-99"
                                        },
                                        "100": {
                                            "$ref": "#/definitions/question6-100"
                                        },
                                        "101": {
                                            "$ref": "#/definitions/question6-101"
                                        }
                                    },
                                    "required": ["99", "100", "101", "102", "103", "104", "105", "111"],
                                    "if": {
                                        "properties": {
                                            "99": {
                                                "properties": {
                                                    "answer": {
                                                        "enum": ["Yes"]
                                                    }
                                                },
                                                "required": ["answer"]
                                            }
                                        },
                                        "required": ["100"]
                                    },
                                    "then": {
                                        "properties": {
                                            "100": {
                                                "properties": {
                                                    "answer": {
                                                        "minLength": 1
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    },
                                    "else": {
                                        "properties": {
                                            "100": {
                                                "properties": {
                                                    "answer": {
                                                        "maxLength": 0
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    },
                                    "if": {
                                        "properties": {
                                            "99": {
                                                "properties": {
                                                    "answer": {
                                                        "enum": ["Yes"]
                                                    }
                                                },
                                                "required": ["answer"]
                                            }
                                        },
                                        "required": ["101"]
                                    },
                                    "then": {
                                        "properties": {
                                            "101": {
                                                "properties": {
                                                    "answer": {
                                                        "minLength": 1
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    },
                                    "else": {
                                        "properties": {
                                            "101": {
                                                "properties": {
                                                    "answer": {
                                                        "maxLength": 0
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "required": ["1"]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Second schema to validate

```
{
    "form_submission": {
        "id": "80035",
        "status": "Incomplete",
        "validated": true,
        "failure_reason": "",
        "sections": {

            "1": {
                "questions": {
                    "99": {
                        "answer": "Yes",
                        "web_validated": true,
                        "web_error_string": "",
                        "server_error_string": ""
                    },
                    "100": {
                        "answer": "",
                        "web_validated": true,
                        "web_error_string": "",
                        "server_error_string": ""
                    },
                    "101": {
                        "answer": "Yes",
                        "web_validated": true,
                        "web_error_string": "",
                        "server_error_string": ""
                    }
                },
                "name": "",
                "validated": true,
                "server_validated": true,
                "notes": ""
            }
        },
        "submitted_section_id": 11
    }
}
```

Added allOf to Schema

```
{
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
    "definitions": {
        "question6-99": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "answer": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "minLength": 1,
                    "enum": ["Yes", "No"]
                }
            }
        },
        "question6-100": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "answer": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "enum": ["Mr", "Ms", "Mrs", "Miss", "Dr", "Rev", "Sir", "Lady", "Lord", "Prof", ""]
                }
            }
        },
        "question6-101": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "answer": {
                    "type": "string"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "form_submission": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "sections": {
                    "type": "object",
                    "properties": {
                        "6": {
                            "type": "object",
                            "properties": {
                                "questions": {
                                    "type": "object",
                                    "properties": {
                                        "99": {
                                            "$ref": "#/definitions/question6-99"
                                        },
                                        "100": {
                                            "$ref": "#/definitions/question6-100"
                                        },
                                        "101": {
                                            "$ref": "#/definitions/question6-101"
                                        }
                                    },
                                    "required": ["99", "100", "101", "102", "103", "104", "105", "111"],
                                    "allOf": [
                                      {
                                        "if": {
                                            "properties": {
                                                "99": {
                                                    "properties": {
                                                        "answer": {
                                                            "enum": ["Yes"]
                                                        }
                                                    },
                                                    "required": ["answer"]
                                                }
                                            },
                                            "required": ["100"]
                                        },
                                        "then": {
                                            "properties": {
                                                "100": {
                                                    "properties": {
                                                        "answer": {
                                                            "minLength": 1
                                                        }
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            }
                                        },
                                        "else": {
                                            "properties": {
                                                "100": {
                                                    "properties": {
                                                        "answer": {
                                                            "maxLength": 0
                                                        }
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }},
                                      {
                                        "if": {
                                            "properties": {
                                                "99": {
                                                    "properties": {
                                                        "answer": {
                                                            "enum": ["Yes"]
                                                        }
                                                    },
                                                    "required": ["answer"]
                                                }
                                            },
                                            "required": ["101"]
                                        },
                                        "then": {
                                            "properties": {
                                                "101": {
                                                    "properties": {
                                                        "answer": {
                                                            "minLength": 1
                                                        }
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            }
                                        },
                                        "else": {
                                            "properties": {
                                                "101": {
                                                    "properties": {
                                                        "answer": {
                                                            "maxLength": 0
                                                        }
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                      }
                                    ]
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "required": ["1"]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You're second example schema only has one `if`, so I can't see where you're going wrong. But, my guess is that you need to wrap your `if`/`then`/`else` in an `allOf`.

Comment: @JasonDesrosiers Apologies, I have updated the OP with the correct schema.

Comment: @JasonDesrosiers I have added another schema that wraps the if-then-else logic inside of an allOf, however this still does not validate how I would expect it to

Comment: In fact the schema now fails to validate anything at all.

Comment: You have it right with the `allOf`. You just have a couple minor errors in your schema that are getting in the way. Sometimes section is "1", other times it's "6". You have several required properties missing in your test data.

Answer (score 31):

If we remove the complicated bits, I think the problem becomes clear.

```
{
  "if": { ... },
  "then": { ... },
  "if": { ... },
  "then": { ... }
}
```

In JSON the value of duplicated keys is undefined. One of these `if`s and one of these `then`s will be ignored by a JSON parser.

You can get around this problem by wrapping your `if`s in an `allOf`.

```
{
  "allOf": [
    {
      "if": { ... },
      "then": { ... }
    },
    {
      "if": { ... },
      "then": { ... }
    }
  ]
}
```

It's good practice to always wrap your `if`/`then`/`else` in `allOf` even if you have only one. This is because a JSON object is by definition unordered. Therefore, some tool might rearrange your keywords splitting up the `if`s and `then`s in a way that makes the schema difficult to decipher.

```
{
  "definitions": {},
  "else": {},
  "if": {},
  "properties": {},
  "then": {},
  "type": "object",
}
```

Comment: thanks for the post, I'm still getting the issue reported in the OP, and my two `if` objects are wrapped in an `allOf` array obj as documented here:
https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/conditionals.html
any other pointers come to mind?

Comment: If your `if`/`then`s are properly wrapped, you shouldn't have this issue unless the validator you are using has a bug. I suggest posting your schema as a new question or on the JSON Schema slack (https://json-schema.org/slack) and someone can help you debug.