# Why do I get Duplicate object key and End of file expected JSON?

Tags: arrays, json, if-statement

I am trying to create a schema that validates coordinates depending on the system I am using: Polar, Cartesian or Cylindrical coordinates. My idea was to use an if statement to validate the used coordinates values according to the system used. The

```
{
"$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
"type": "array",
"minItems": 3,
"maxItems": 3,
"items": 
{
    "system": 
    {
        "enum": ["Cartesian", "Cylindric","Spherical"],
        "description": "The type of the system"
     },
        "if":
        {
            "items": 
            {
                "system":
                {
                    "const": "Cartesian"
                }
            }
        },

        "then": 
        {
            "items":
            {
                "x": 
                {
                    "type": "number"
                },
                "y": 
                {
                    "type": "number"
                 },
                "z": 
                {
                    "type": "number"
                }     
            },
            "required": ["x","y","z"] 
        } ,
        "if":
        {
            "items": 
            {
                "system":
                {
                "const": "Spherical"
                }
             }
        },
        "then": 
         {
            "items":
            {
                "r": 
                {
                    "type": "number"
                },
                "theta":
                {
                    "type": "number",
                    "minimum": "0",
                    "maximum": "360"
                },
                "phi":
                {
                    "type": "number",
                    "minimum": "0",
                    "maximum": "180"
                }
            },
            "required": ["x","y","z"]
        },
        "if":
        {
            "items": 
            {
                "system":
                {
                    "const": "Cylindrical"
                }
            }
        },
        "then": 
        {
            "items":
            {
                "r": 
                {
                    "type": "number"
                },
                "theta":
                {
                    "type": "number",
                    "minimum": "0",
                    "maximum": "360"
                },
                "z":
                {
                    "type": "number"
                }
            },
            "required": ["x","y","z"]
        }
    }
}
```

}

In the end I get the following errors:

- End of file expected
- Duplicate object key

Since I am new to JSON can someone please explain what I am missing here?

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54712494/7381844) answer. The main problem is that you have multiple keys named `if` and `then`. In json keys must always be unique.

Comment: JSON is used for data structures not programming so I'm not sure what you are doing.  What language are you using to parse the json?  'End of file expected' probably means you have one too many "}" in your json.  Duplicate key probably means you have repeated a key - in your case at least "if" and "then" although the Javascript JSON parser does not seem to throw that error.